# Serialization not working on Android - Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, serialization

**Problem**

My problem is that I'm not not able to serialize and de-serialize a list on Android when I build my game into an .apk. The code works fine in the Unity Editor. I'm not able to get any error messages because the problem only arises when I build the game.

**Setting Path to File**

```
private void Start () {
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) {
        // Android
        string oriPath = Path.Combine (Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Data.xml");

        // Android only use WWW to read file
        WWW reader = new WWW (oriPath);
        while (!reader.isDone) { }

        string realPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Data";
        File.WriteAllBytes (realPath, reader.bytes);

        dbPath = realPath;
    } else {
        // iOS and Unity Editor
        dbPath = Path.Combine (Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Data.xml");
    }
}
```

**Loading from File**

```
public void LoadItems () {
    FileStream stream;

    if (!File.Exists(dbPath)) {
        stream = new FileStream (dbPath, FileMode.Create);
        stream.Close ();
        stream.Dispose ();
    }

    stream = new FileStream (dbPath, FileMode.Open);

    if (stream.Length != 0) {
        materialDB = serializer.Deserialize (stream) as MaterialDB;
        stream.Close ();
    }

    stream.Dispose ();
}
```

**Saving to File**

```
public void SaveItems () {
    FileStream stream = new FileStream (dbPath, FileMode.Create);

    serializer.Serialize (stream, materialDB);
    stream.Close ();

    stream.Dispose ();
}
```

Comment: This is binary not xml serialization.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the tag

Comment: Edit the whole question and also remove references to XML. EDIT: In fact, don't worry with the Edit. Use json.  See duplicate for how to save data. Forget about binary serialization.